# malloc and realloc functions

Tags: c

```
int main( )    
{
    int *p;
    p=(int *)malloc(20);
    printf("%u",p); \\ printing some memory adress 
    p=(int *)realloc(p,0);
    printf("%u",p); \\ printing as 0
    printf("%u",*p); \\ printing the value as 0
}
```

Now my question is the statement `relloc` working as the `free()` function as the pointer `p` is pointing to the `NULL` and `NULL` value in it. Will that 20 bytes be freed?

Comment: Use `"%p"` to print pointers.

Comment: comments in C are indicated by *forward* slashes, not *backward* slashes, I've left that uncorrected in my edit.

Comment: If p is NULL, you can't dereference it...

Comment: I'd just to make a recommendation here: do not cast malloc calls. Read this for some rationale: http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it may not be freed in *all* circumstances. C99 has this to say in `7.20.3.4 The realloc function`:

> If memory for the new object cannot be allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged.

Now you may think that an allocation of zero bytes couldn't possibly fail but the standard doesn't mandate that. It says, for zero-sized objects:

> If the size of the space requested is zero, the behaviour is implementation defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behaviour is as if the size were some non-zero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

So, if your implementation is one of those that *doesn't* return NULL for a zero-size allocation, and it requires *some* housekeeping information for each allocation, and the memory arena is *so* full that you can't store even another housekeeping header, and it's not smart enough just to split the current allocation and return most of it to the arena, it may fail a zero-size `realloc` and hence not free the original memory.

Now this is a (very) edge case depending on a lot of decisions made in the implementation, most of which may seem bizarre to people with experience of writing them. Unfortunately, we have to allow for the edge cases as well :-)

If it really worries you, I'd just change:

```
p=(int *)realloc(p,0);
```

into:

```
free (p) ; p = NULL;
```

---

A couple of other points.

1. Comment marjers are forward slashes `/`, not backslashes.
2. You are not allowed to dereference `p` in that final line whether or not your implementation returns NULL for a zero-size allocation. See my second quote above where it states: "except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object".
3. You shouldn't really cast the return values from `malloc`-type calls. This is a hangover from the dim dark past before C had a `void*`, and `malloc` returned `char*`. The problem with doing so nowadays is, if you forget to include `stdlib.h`, problems can be hidden from you.

Comment: I'd also like to add that `p = realloc(p, n);` is incorrect. The proper way to use `realloc` is `void *tmp = realloc(p, n); if(!tmp) { /* handle realloc error */ } p = tmp;`

Comment: Great explanation. And i dint even realise he used back slash.

Answer (score 1):

If the size given to `realloc` is 0 together with an allocated pointer then it [will free the memory the pointer points to and will return NULL](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/).

Which brings the next question:

Why do you do this then:

```
printf("%u",*p); \\ printing the value as 0
```

`p` is NULL at this point, and you're still dereferencing it. What for? What do you expect to happen here?

Comment: NULL actually i read NULL means 0 so it must be pointing to zeroth location so i wanna know the data in it

Comment: @jack - NULL doesn't have to be 0 (although it usually is). Regardless, dereferencing NULL brings undefined behavior (crashes, memory corruption, blue screens, etc), and you knowingly do it in your code. You **cannot** see what's in the "zeroth location" because it's not a memory you're allowed to access.

Comment: sorry @littleadv i just keep on doing things with different syntaxes to know how they work so i wanted to see the zero location.i have a doubt on unaryoperatos but it says u have to wait 20 min can i ask it here

Answer (score 0):

First this is very platform dependent. Your `realloc` call definitely does not work as a free... using the pointer as you did would get some kind of segmentation fault or crash if it did set p to the `NULL` pointer...

Whether the `realloc` will "free" the 20 bytes or not (again) completely depends on the OS / library implementing that `realloc`.

EDIT:

From the GNU C lib :

```
/*
  REALLOC_ZERO_BYTES_FREES should be set if a call to
  realloc with zero bytes should be the same as a call to free.
  This is required by the C standard. Otherwise, since this malloc
  returns a unique pointer for malloc(0), so does realloc(p, 0).
*/
```

By default, this is defined to 1, but other implementation can change that behavior...

Comment: Who downvoted this? In C99 `realloc` with 0 size is implementation defined. It can be the same as `free` _or_ `malloc(0)`. Which it ought to be is not clear, so I see this as an improvement on the standard's part.

Comment: @Chris, I believe C99 has been quoted in one of the answers for your satisfaction.

Comment: @littleadv - It has. I'm posting from my iPhone so I'm a little behind everyone else. (Otherwise _I_ would've been quoting the standard.)

Comment: i posted some other question based on pointers help me to get through it thank you

Answer (score 0):

The C90 standard specifically said:

> If size is zero and ptr is not a null pointer, the object it points to is freed.

So this is how C90 and C++ implementations should behave - nice, simple, and straightforward.

However, for some reason that sentence was removed from the C99 standard.

POSIX currently has the sentence that's in the C90 standard. But, The Austin Group (which handles some aspects of the POSIX standardization) [has a defect open on this](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=374).  Note that the defect report indicates that BSD has the following behavior for `realloc(ptr,0)`:

> realloc(ptr,0) only gives NULL on alloc failure, ptr unchanged, errno is ENOMEM

Which I read as saying that `ptr` is not freed (I don't have a BSD system to check this on).

In other words, it's kind of a mess what should/will happen with `realloc(ptr,0)` - I wouldn't depend on it freeing the memory. Call `free()` of that's what you want to do.

I wonder what the rationale for C99 removing that sentence was...

In fact, the C99 standard actually seems to preclude `realloc(ptr,0)` from simply freeing the block (ie., it doesn't seem to leave this implementation defined at all). The C99 standard says:

> ... If memory for the new object cannot be allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged
>
> **Returns**
>
> The realloc function returns a pointer to the new object (which may have the same value as a pointer to the old object), or a null pointer if the new object could not be allocated.

So, if `realloc()` returns `NULL` then the new object could not be allocated and the old object must not be freed. But if `realloc()` returns non-NULL, then you still have the object that must be freed (or some new memory object that must be freed).  In other words, if `realloc(ptr,0)` returns `NULL` then you are still responsible for freeing `ptr`.  If `realloc(ptr,0)` returns a non-null pointer, then you're responsible for freeing whatever pointer is returned.

I guess maybe that's why C99 removed that sentence.  Note however, that many (most?) implementations do free the block when `realloc(ptr,0)` is called, regardless of what C99 might have to say about it.